# What is the correct way to ask the following thing?

Tags: phrase-usage

I want to ask about someone's status whether he / she is married or single or divorced. I need to write it in a document.  What's the way to ask about that as well as to write it in a document as a format? Does "**family status**" work in this context?

***For example:***

> "What is your family status, please?"

Or in a document:

> **Family status**: Single / married / divorced

Answer (score 3):

The usual expression is "marital status". Possible answers can include single, married, widowed, separated, divorced, and maybe others (?) that I can't think of right now.

Comment: On census and other forms, 'family status' can be used to indicate whether a person is the responsible caregiver for a child.

Comment: I'm a lot more used to hearing *relationship status*. *Marital* simply implies married or not. Relationships can be more nuanced than that. (*I'm dating someone*, for instance.) But if the form is only concerned with married or not, then *marital* is just fine. The context of the question isn't entirely clear. (When seeing a psychologist, for instance, they might use *relationship status* on their intake forms instead—because they want that additional information.)